# How do you make a chocolate chip cookie where the chips remain gooey after baked and cooled?

Tags: chocolate

Just had a chocolate chip cookie at local bakery.  Cookie was crunchy with gooey chocolate chips inside, like right out of oven gooey, but cookie was cooled.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Let me point you to our [tour] and our [help] - good places to ge started and for more info on how this site and the whole Stack Exchange network works. Looking forward to more contributions from you!

Comment: Two possibilities: a very fresh cookie - the chocolate can stay soft after cooling for a little while; not proper chocolate but something softer.

Answer (score 2):

Naturally, chocolate is solid at room temperature. The only reason that chocolate chips are ever gooey is because they have been warmed recently enough that the chocolate has not yet reached it's solid state.

You may want to consider making your own chocolate chips with a little bit more liquid than normal to get the soft texture.

> **Some Easy Ways to Warm Them Include:**
>
> - Throw the cookies up on your car windshield for a while.
> - Stick them in the oven for a minute (generally dries them out)
> - Put them in the Microwave for ~10-15 sec

Comment: "The only reason they are ever gooey..." - well, not exactly. As you say they could've used some kind of less solid chocolate instead of normal chips, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean that chocolate chips are sold at room temperature and they are solid. In order to make _normal_ chocolate chips gooey, you need to warm them. A recipe could be made to be gooey at room temperature.

Comment: Oh, I read "they" as referring to the OP's question, not chocolate chips. Tweaked your answer, all good.

Comment: We always used to put them in a microwave for ~10-15 seconds... they'd get soft without drying out usually.

Comment: I had some cookies that had been left in a warm car ... I don't know what the temperature was, but I was told it had been left while they were at church (so would've been a little more than an hour, I think).  They had that fresh-out-of-the-oven goodness.